Including copyright preambles in protoc-compiled source code?
I have a foo.proto file that gets compiled to python with protoc and included in a python package that is then built in to a wheel for distribution.
Is there a way to include a copyright notice preamble in this generated foo_pb2.py file?  The current header for this file appears like this for me:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: foo.proto

And for example I'd like something like
# Copyright (c) 2024 charlestoncrabb. All Rights Reserved.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: foo.proto

I feel like I can't just ignore the DO NOT EDIT! part there and manually (or part of the wheel build process) insert my own copyright notice above that :) but maybe I can?
Or since there's the source: foo.proto part there, does it suffice to include the foo.proto file in the python package as well, with the copyright notice at the top of that file?
This seems like it would be a common problem, but I cannot find any guidance/best practices online regarding this; any help is appreciated!

The protobuf/LICENSE confers ownership of protoc-generated code on the owner of (protocol buffer) source file used to generate it. Stack overflow is for programming questions. You may be better placed asking legal question elsewhere.

In principal, you'd not distribute the source code generated by protoc. Instead, you'd distribute the .proto file (with whatever copyright statements you like in comments), and the build system you specify / supply calls protoc to generate the source on demand.
At least, that's the idea. However, last time I looked there's a bit of a problem. Because of the things that Google has now inculded in the source for the protoc compiler itself, many Linux distributions seem to be falling behind where GPB has got to.
Specifically, it's Abseil, libabsl, which is Google's idea of how to improve on the standard C++ library. And the way Google seem to use it is that it's compiled as part of the application using it (protoc in this instance), apparently making life a bit tough for Linux distros. See this slightly old discussion here. Certainly, when I recently installed protoc from packages supplied as a standard part of Ubuntu, the version I got was ancient.
I think the problem comes from the fact that libabsl becomes a dependency for the generated code, and potentially if your application uses another piece of code that also depends on libabsl, you can run into a situation where your code cannot be compiled because you need different verisons of the same library. Also I ran into issues with things like C++/14, C++/17; libabsl used one, I was using the other, and we couldn't meet in the middle (or something like that). See example issues here on GitHub
The long of it is that, relying on a recipient to be able to get all the dependencies for protoc / GPB together reliably is now quite hard work.

The GitHub issue
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/issues/1610 is about propagating the header from the proto file into the header section of the generated code.
This specific issue is for Swift and not for Python, but a similar issue could be created for Python if it doesn't exist yet.
In the meantime, you could use the ed command line tool to add a header to your generated files.
Create a file called, e.g. proto_header_py.ed
1i
# Copyright (c) 2024 charlestoncrabb. All Rights Reserved.
# If you need more lines, put them here.
w
q

Then use the following command to add the header to the generated code:
ed - foo_pb2.py < proto_header_py.ed

